# Database (Java) / Which way would be the efficient/best?

Tags: java, javafx, jdbc

Whats the best way to make the program? I connected the program to a database through JDBC. I have 2 integer typed columns.

In my program, I put on GUI in a table the number1, number2 and number1+number2. What would be the best: if I store the number1+number2 as a third column in database and all I do I read from database and put on gui OR read the first, second column, sum them and then put on GUI?

Comment: It's best to avoid storing redundant data.

Comment: You can get all three columns in your query results.

Comment: Yes, it could work both ways, having 3 columns or having 2 columns and calculate third. But which would be resource efficient?

Comment: Why not run it both ways and collect some timing data? You would then have the answer you want.

Comment: In case you are thinking about relational-database do some research on how data is to be designed and also what is data normalization. Also, for the kind of data you have mentioned in the post one can consider to store it in a plain text file.

Comment: @shmosel - ..... in most situations.

Comment: You can ask the database to calculate things for you in your query.

Answer (score 4):

You are basically asking if it is more efficient to store the result of a computation in the database, or to compute it each time it is needed.

The Answer is: **It depends** on the cost of the computation versus the cost of storing the result.

In your example, the cost of adding two numbers together is trivial, but the cost of storing the result *may be non-trivial*; e.g. if you have billions of number pairs.  For other examples, the answer will be the opposite.

---

However, there is more to this than just efficiency.  Other reasons why redundancy can be bad include:

- You are wasting space in the database; e.g. a `sum` column might mean up to 50% more space in the table for actual data.
- The redundant copies have to be kept up to date; e.g. when you update a row's `number1` or `number2` field, you have to update `sum` field as well.
- Redundancy makes schema migration more complicated.  (Hard to illustrate convincingly with your example ...)

Read up on "database normalization"; see @Basil Bourque's answer!

Comment: The space the `sum` column could be greater than 50% if you create an index for it. On the other hand if many queries containing`ORDER BY sum`, `MAX(sum)`, `MIN(sum)`, `GROUP BY sum` or similar are executed,the computational cost is greatly reduced.Furthermore computational cost also depends on the write/read ratio.If for every write access on a row there are 500 read accesses that include the `sum` column, the cost of the additions is 500(and only the additions)times higher than for storing the data in a column.The effect is the opposite, if there are 500 write accesses for every read access.

Comment: These points are correct.  But the basic point I am trying to get across is **IT DEPENDS**

Answer (score 3):

## Database normalization

Learn about [*database normalization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

A primary goal of relational database design is to avoid and eliminate redundant/repeated data.

So ideally you would store your two numbers, and dynamically calculate the third as needed. You may choose to let your application make that calculation, or you can have the database run the calculation by reporting a third virtual column as part of your query. With any serious database such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), you can generate values on-the-fly to be returned alongside your retrieved values.

However, there are times when we choose to break the rules and *denormalize* some aspect of our table design. Almost always this motivation is some measurable proven performance problem. But as a beginner, strive to keep your design normalized.